# Using @InjectMock for panache repository fails when using rest-assured

Tags: testing, mockito, rest-assured, quarkus

We have a simple Quarkus project implementing an n-tier architecture. We would like to test the API using Rest Assured, by mocking the Repository layer.

```
@QuarkusTest
class ContactResourceTest {
    @InjectMock
    private ThirdPartyPanacheRepository thirdPartyRepository;

    @Test
    void doTest() throws BusinessException {
        given()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(new MyDTO())
                .when()
                    .post("/my/route")
                .then()
                    .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: Failed to create test instance

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.initTestState(QuarkusTestExtension.java:397)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:378)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:333)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.initTestState(QuarkusTestExtension.java:394)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.company.repository.ThirdPartyPanacheRepository_ClientProxy.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.3+12-LTS
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.3+12-LTS
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type: null
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.internal.CreateMockitoMocksCallback.createMockAndSetTestField(CreateMockitoMocksCallback.java:36)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.internal.CreateMockitoMocksCallback.beforeAll(CreateMockitoMocksCallback.java:27)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type: null
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDefinition$Sort.describe(TypeDefinition.java:228)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection$OfMethodParameter.resolve(TypeDescription.java:6623)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection.accept(TypeDescription.java:6106)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$TypeSubstituting.getType(ParameterDescription.java:1057)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterList$AbstractBase.asTypeList(ParameterList.java:109)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asTypeToken(MethodDescription.java:845)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default$Key$Harmonized.of(MethodGraph.java:922)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default$Key$Store.registerTopLevel(MethodGraph.java:1107)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.doAnalyze(MethodGraph.java:634)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.analyze(MethodGraph.java:596)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.analyzeNullable(MethodGraph.java:615)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.doAnalyze(MethodGraph.java:629)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.analyze(MethodGraph.java:596)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.analyzeNullable(MethodGraph.java:615)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.doAnalyze(MethodGraph.java:629)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.compile(MethodGraph.java:567)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$AbstractBase.compile(MethodGraph.java:465)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default.prepare(MethodRegistry.java:471)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:207)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:198)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3404)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:173)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:63)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1908)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1817)
    ... 66 more
```

I also tried without using `@InjectMock`, instead using `QuarkusMock.installMockForType` in a `@BeforeAll` method, [as documented here](https://quarkus.io/blog/mocking/). This fails at the moment when the business code attempts to call a method on the repository, with the following error:

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   org.mockito.codegen.ThirdPartyRepository$MockitoMock$1469313994 cannot
>   be cast to class com.company.repository.ThirdPartyPanacheRepository
>   (org.mockito.codegen.ThirdPartyRepository$MockitoMock$1469313994 is in
>   unnamed module of loader
>   net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader @7836c79;
>   com.company.repository.ThirdPartyPanacheRepository is in unnamed
>   module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader
>   @7072bc39)

How can I install a mock for my test?

Comment: Hey @Kricket, I don't suppose this is an issue with Rest Assured, also I saw this on the logs `Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.company.repository.ThirdPartyPanacheRepository_ClientProxy.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.` which is a bit ominous

Comment: I suspect it's due to mixing Rest Assured with Quarkus with mocking. Quarkus tests mess around with the ClassLoader, and mocking requires some extra work. Their examples all deal with injecting a bean and calling methods directly instead of hitting the API.